# How to pass header and body to HttpSendRequest

Tags: c++, http, web

I'm working on sample c++ code to post buffer data to the URL using HTTP but I'm facing unable to post data, its throwing header not correct.

Here my requirement is to post a text file as body and header info ( name, age, place ) to " "test.php" url.

help me how to post header and body to the `HttpSendRequest`

```
char hdrs[255];                  //Headers
char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
long lSize;                      //File size
size_t result;


// Open file
pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\user.txt", "rb");
if (pFile == NULL) return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;

// obtain file size:
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
content = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
if (content == NULL) return ERROR_MEMORY;

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread(content, 1, lSize, pFile);
if (result != lSize) return ERROR_SIZE;

// terminate
fclose(pFile);

//allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

// header
sprintf(hdrs, "Name=xxx&age=xx&place=xxxx");

// body
sprintf(buffer, content);


//Open internet connection
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(L"WinSock", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hSession == NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN;

HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession,"localhost", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
if (hConnect == NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;

HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST","test.php", NULL, NULL, (const char**)"*/*\0", 0, 1);
if (hRequest == NULL) return ERROR_INTERNET_REQ;

BOOL sent = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));
if (!sent) return ERROR_INTERNET_SEND;

//close any valid internet-handles
InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
```

Comment: Note: the only thing C++ about this is the compiler you're using, this is written completely in a C style. Please select which language you want answers for because they will be very different.

Comment: "header not correct" literally means header is wrong. All is about HTTP protocol, not about C++

Comment: "Name=xxx&age=xx&place=xxxx" does not look like the right way to specify HTTP headers. Have you researched example usages of HttpSendRequest?

Comment: @TheUndeadFish there very less resources related to HttpSendRequest in google search so I added here, if you have any good examples please post here.

Comment: Among my first search results for simply "HttpSendRequest" is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106816/how-to-contruct-httpsendrequest-method-of-wininet You might notice the format `"Content-Type: text/html\nMySpecialHeder: whatever"` looks rather different than what you have.